# (xcode) I want to have a long press on a button cause a keyboard to pop up

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, swift3

I need to have the app I am making have a keyboard pop up on a button long press.

I know how to recognize the long press but the problem is having the keyboard pop up and letting the keyboard know which var to edit.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: To be more specific I want the button to be a name so I would have:

```
p1s1PlayerName.setTitle(String(player1name), for UIControlState.normal)
```

and then I would have the long press pop up a keyboard. The keyboard would then need to edit

```
var player1name = "TextInputFromKeyboard"
```

full code that needs to be edited:

```
var player1name = "John"

func userLongPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("user long pressed")
    p1s1PlayerName.becomeFirstResponder()
}

@IBOutlet var p1s1PlayerName: UIButton!

@IBAction func p1s1LongPressPlayerName(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // This is where I don't know what to put to call to the function and have the keyboard pop up
}
```

Comment: `which var`  means?

Comment: @Mr.UB sorry for being unclear. To be more specific I want the button to be a name so I would have: `p1s1PlayerName.setTitle(String(player1name), for: UIControlState.normal)` and then I would have the long press pop up a keyboard. The keyboard would then need to edit `var player1name = "TextInputFromKeyboard"`

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your long press, have the selector called include the following code.

```
textfieldToEdit.becomeFirstResponder()
```

If you want there to be some informational text for the user, just assign it to the placeholder.

```
textfieldToEdit.placeholder = "Enter name here"
```

Comment: `@IBAction func p1s1LongPressPlayerName(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  p1s1PlayerName.becomeFirstResponder()
 }` So I set my long press code to something like this but when I long press still nothing happens. Sorry I'm still new :(

Answer (score 1):

initially add long gesture to your button like

```
 let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPress))
p1s1PlayerName.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

and call method like

```
func userLongPressed(_ sender: Any) {
 print("user long pressed")
   yourTextfieldName.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

for button single press

```
p1s1PlayerName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.userTapped), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
p1s1PlayerName.setTitle(String(player1name), for UIControlState.normal)
```

and action like

```
func userTapped(_ sender: Any) {
print("user tapped")
 }
```

Comment: `func userLongPressed(_ sender: Any) {
  print("user long pressed")
  p1s1PlayerName.becomeFirstResponder()
 }
 @IBAction func p1s1LongPressPlayerName(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  userLongPressed(Any.self)
}`

So my code for the long press looks like this, and it prints "user long pressed" but still no keyboard. I'm having trouble understanding what your original code meant as I am still new so sorry if I did something wrong that you already explained.

Comment: @Baker2795 - ok, what is this **userLongPressed(Any.self)**

Comment: Not even sure where that came from. So I have the 'userLongPressed' function outside of the longpress function. So what do I put inside the longpress function in order to call to the 'userLongPressed' function?

Comment: @Baker2795 - i partially understand ur comment can you update the question once, with your full and updated code

Comment: @Baker2795 - p1s1PlayerName is UIButton not UITextfied, you can't use Keyboard popup in here, in this place use one textfield or UIalertController for get the value and again insert the value to your button